# ConditionalPanel in R shiny not working for the second set of condition

Tags: shiny

I have a problem with the use of conditionalPanel in R shiny. Basically, the first condition (condition = "input.year == 2011") is working which gives me the right leafleft map. However, when I use the second condition (condition = "input.year == 2012") i got an empty map! Any suggestion on how to get out from this issue?

Here my server and ui:

#### ui

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(

# Title
titlePanel("Greater London Area, Satellite and UK AIR data"),

sidebarLayout(

sidebarPanel(
selectInput("year", "Choose a year", c("YEAR 2011" = "2011", "YEAR 2012" = "2012")),

conditionalPanel(
condition = "input.year == 2011",
 selectInput("variable", "Choose a Layer", c("PM25_SAT" = "pm25_mean"))),

conditionalPanel(
condition = "input.year == 2012",
selectInput("variable", "Choose a Layer", c("URB_COVER" = "URB_Cover_nc")))
),

        # Show leaflet map with a text div reporting the selected date and extents 
 mainPanel(
    leafletOutput('myMap', height = 500, width = 800)
    )
   )))
```

#### server

```
  ####### Load data first 
PM25_sat <- readOGR(dsn = "Copia.geojson",layer = "OGRGeoJSON")

popup_PM25_sat <- paste0("<strong>PM<sub>2.5</sub> (<font  face=symbol>m</font>g/m<sup>3</sup>): </strong>", 
                      PM25_sat$pm25_mean)

   #### colors for the GeoJSON layer
  qpal_SAT <- colorQuantile("Blues", PM25_sat$pm25_mean, n = 7)

  #### colors for the GeoJSON layer legend
   pal_SAT <- colorNumeric(
  palette = "Blues",
  domain = PM25_sat$pm25_mean)

 ###### Load geotiff file 
URB_Cover_nc <- raster::raster("URB_cover.tif")

pal_URB <- colorNumeric(c("#FFFFCC", "#41B6C4","#0C2C84"),  getValues(URB_Cover_nc),
                     na.color = "transparent")

 #######################################################################

  shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  map = leaflet() %>% addTiles() %>% setView(-2, 52.5, 6)


   finalMap <- reactive({
    PM25_Layer <- input$variable
     YEAR <- input$year


      if (YEAR == "2011" & PM25_Layer == "pm25_mean")
       return(map %>% addPolygons(data = PM25_sat,
                                  stroke = FALSE, smoothFactor = 0.2, 
                                  fillOpacity = 0.5, 
                                  color = ~ qpal_SAT(pm25_mean),
                                  popup = popup_PM25_sat) %>%
                  addLegend("bottomright", pal = pal_SAT, values = PM25_sat$pm25_mean,
                  title = "<br><strong>PM<sub>2.5</sub> (<font face=symbol>m</font>g/m<sup>3</sup>) Sat : </strong>",
                  labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = ""), opacity = 1))


      if (YEAR == "2012" & PM25_Layer == "URB_Cover_nc")
        return(map %>% addRasterImage(URB_Cover_nc, 
                                  colors = pal_URB, 
                                  opacity = 0.6) %>%
         addLegend("bottomright",pal = pal_URB, values = getValues(URB_Cover_nc),
         title = "<br><strong>PM<sub>2.5</sub> (<font face=symbol>m</font>g/m<sup>3</sup>) URB Cover: </strong>",
         labFormat = labelFormat(prefix = ""),
         opacity = 0.6))

 else return (map) 
 })

output$myMap = renderLeaflet(finalMap())  
})
```

Comment: The above example isn't reproducible, you need to include all the data and variables you use to produce your `leaflet` map. Conditional panels working fine on their own, as they should.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of your problem? Try to remove everything that is not relevant to your question - and maybe you'll find out the answer on your own

Comment: Thanks you all for your feedback. I have simplified the script related to my problem. Basically i do not have an idea on how I could better change the script. The first layer is a GeoJSON file and it has been assigned to the year 2011 and it is correctly displayed. The second layer is a tiff file and it has been assigned to the year 2012 but it is not displayed. It seem that only the first condition is displayed...the script run the "else return (map)" when the second conditionalPanel is selected, why?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have solved the problem.
I have defined two variables: "variable_1" and "variable_2" for the year 2011 and the year 2012, respectively.